# HtmlUnit webpage status code

Tags: java, http-status-code-404, htmlunit

I am trying to get the web status for a given page. However when its a 404 error, the page does not return the status code, rather it throws and error.

```
int status= webClient.getPage("website").getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
System.out.println( status);
```

Any Ideas?

I am looking to see when sites time out, however for testing purposes I malformed the url of the desired website to see if I can even see a 404.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240221/htmlunit-404-error-for-scripts-within-page)

You can do this:

```
webclient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(False)
```

****EDIT ***

This does print out your status code:

```
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
 int status = webClient.getPage("http://google.co.uk/ffffff").getWebResponse()
            .getStatusCode();
 System.out.println(status);
```

Prints out 404 - your status code.

Comment: No, I want to get the status code of a webpage. Even if its a 404 error.

Comment: Updated my answer. it works unless I'm missing out on what your asking. 404 is the http status code

Comment: Your case given works, however the specific website I am trying to use does not work for some odd reason.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? what exception does it throw?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can continue to allow the FailingHttpStatusCodeException to be thrown (true). Then within the catch clause get the error status code.

```
...
int status = 0;
Object page = null;
try {
     page = webClient.getPage(webRequest);
     webClient.close();
     if (page instanceof UnexpectedPage) {
         status = ((UnexpectedPage) page).getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
     } else if (page instanceof HtmlPage) {
         status = ((HtmlPage) page).getWebResponse().getStatusCode();
     }
     // do something else ...
} catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
     if (e instanceof FailingHttpStatusCodeException) {
          status = ((FailingHttpStatusCodeException) e).getStatusCode();
     }
     // do something else ...
}
```